# Custom Resolution Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, display-resolution, xrandr, modelines

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and as usual the option for display resolutions were only 1024x768 and 800x600.
My monitor is **AOC e943Fwsk** which does not officially support **1920x1080**.
but I also have windows 10 installed on this computer and through  **Radeon** software I can add custom resolutions, so I added **1920x1080** and it works. In the monitor setting menu in extra information it shows:

```
resolution: 1920(H)X1080(V)
H.Frequency: 68KHz
V.Frequency: 60Hz
```

Now the problem is when I try to set **1920x1080** resolution in ubuntu using **xrandr** my monitor says `input not supported`. I don't understand why it works in windows but not in ubuntu. Maybe the **modeline** needs to be modified but I don't know what to modify in it.
After that that I tried to add **1600x900** and it works but in the monitor menu extra info it says:

```
resolution: 1440(H)X900(V)
H.Frequency: 56KHz
V.Frequency: 60Hz
```

but the resolution is **1600x900** in ubuntu.
I know this is the difference between `Active Signal Resolution` and `Desktop Resolution` which I know how to solve in windows but don't have any idea in ubuntu. But it's not the main problem. The problem is adding **1920x1080**.
I am attaching custom resolution info in Radeon software and Windows setting.

Here is what I did:

```
$ cvt 1920 1080
output: # 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync80
$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --addmode DVI-0 "1920x1080_60.00"
```

After that this resolution was added in settings so changed to it but `input not supported`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suggest you edit your question above with how you ran `cvt` and `xrandr` to add the custom resolution and the results of those commands. You say that maybe the modeline needs to be modified but you have not shown how you added your modeline so people cannot see what might be wrong or how to suggest a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a cvt with reduced blanking mode:
`cvt -r 1920 1080`

I can see your windows custom resolution seems to have a pixel clock of 148.5MHz (148500 kHz) but CVT modeline pixel clock is 173Mhz. It may be the monitor can handle the lower pixel clock mode you added in windows but not the higher pixel clock mode you added in Ubuntu.

The reduced blanking mode should generate a modeline with a lower pixel clock value.

What's the reason you want to run the monitor above its native resolution?

Comment: That actually worked. It produced 138.5 MHz. After adding it and changing the resolution in settings it works. Now I added these commands in ~/.profile so i can use this resolution. I want that resolution just to see more information in applications and stuff, I am just used to it in windows 10. Thank you very much.